# Firefox developer tools Color Scheme for Sublime text 2

Tags: firefox, sublime-text-2, themes, firefox-developer-tools

How to find a Color Scheme (file "*.tmTheme") with Firefox developer tools for Sublime Text 2?

Comment: This question is very unclear. What exactly are you looking for? A theme for Sublime that looks like the Firefox developer tools?

Comment: @MattDMo: Yes. Color Scheme.

Answer (score 1):

I made an approximation of the light theme for myself and just [put it on GitHub](https://github.com/willlma/firefox-tmTheme) for you. Feel free to improve on it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the Fox [Theme](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Theme%20-%20Fox), it just looks like Mozilla's Firefox Developer Edition and it is available for ST2 and ST3:

> A custom UI and syntax theme for Sublime Text 2/3. Based on Mozilla's Firefox Developer Edition and @kkga's Spacegray.